# Sommer mapping mmer2 function to mmer

Tags: r

I have a matrix with the following columns: 2 fixed effects, a dependent variable and 2 IDs which match the rows and columns of my variance/covariance matrix (GRM1 and GRM2). With the previous version of sommer I used the mmer2 function

mmer2_result <- mmer2(y ~ fixed_effect1 + fixed_effect2, random=~g(id1)+g(id2),G=list(id1=GRM1, id2=GRM2),rcov=~units, silent=TRUE, data=data,constraint=FALSE)

How would I map this over to the mmer function in the updated package?

Answer (score 0):

Please take some time to read the documentation, there are plenty of examples showing how the changes are implemented in the new version. The answer:

```
mmer_result <- mmer(y ~ fixed_effect1 + fixed_effect2, random=~vm(id1, Gu=GRM1)+vm(id2, Gu=GRM2),rcov=~units, silent=TRUE, data=data)
```

Best,